# JMeter test with smart card and knox

Tags: jmeter, smartcard, knox-gateway

I am trying to test an application which is behind a KnoxToken service and the user is required to use a smartcard and his PIN. Using JMeter to test apps without security features is working as expected.

In this case I get an error: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake

From Jmeter-> Options -> SSL Manager , I am importing a certificate that I found in my machine. When I run and I am prompted to enter a password. After typing the smart card password (once per JMeter session) it seems to continue, but then again it breaks... I assume that this resolved the smart card authentication and that is breaks when communicating with knox...

from the log file:

```
2019-10-25 17:09:42,768 WARN o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: https.use.cached.ssl.context property must be set to false to ensure Multiple Certificates are used
2019-10-25 17:09:42,768 INFO o.a.j.c.KeystoreConfig: Configuring Keystore with (preload: 'True', startIndex: 0, endIndex: -1, clientCertAliasVarName: 'certAlias')
2019-10-25 17:09:42,768 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: JmeterKeyStore Location: C:\Users\MI\Desktop\FFFRootCA21.crt type JKS
2019-10-25 17:09:42,768 INFO o.a.j.u.SSLManager: KeyStore created OK
2019-10-25 17:09:47,648 ERROR o.a.j.u.SSLManager: Problem loading keystore: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.security.provider.KeyStoreDelegator.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$DualFormatJKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.keystore.JmeterKeyStore.load(JmeterKeyStore.java:117) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.getKeyStore(SSLManager.java:132) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.SSLManager.configureKeystore(SSLManager.java:290) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:99) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.config.KeystoreConfig.testStarted(KeystoreConfig.java:63) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.notifyTestListenersOfStart(StandardJMeterEngine.java:206) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.run(StandardJMeterEngine.java:381) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]

2019-10-25 17:09:47,857 WARN o.a.j.p.h.s.HTTPSamplerBase: Existing CookieManager HTTP Cookie Manager superseded by HTTP Cookie Manager

2019-10-25 17:09:47,862 WARN o.a.j.p.h.c.KerberosManager: Could not log in user 
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for JMeter
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.lambda$getSubjectForUser$0(KerberosManager.java:68) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.KerberosManager.getSubjectForUser(KerberosManager.java:83) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager.getSubjectForUrl(AuthManager.java:294) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:831) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:574) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:67) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1231) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1220) [ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:622) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:546) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:486) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:253) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.1.1 r1855137]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_171]

thank you
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking into `No LoginModules configured for JMeter` part of the log it appears that you're trying to test the application which uses [Kerberos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol))

So my expectation is that you should perform proper configuration in the [jaas.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/jaas.conf) and [krb5.conf](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/v5_1_1/bin/krb5.conf) files (both located in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation), the configuration must match your [application Kerberos details](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP3/HDP-3.1.4/configuring-proxy-knox/content/configuring_knox_with_a_secured_hadoop_cluster.html).

Check out [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter/) article to learn about setting up JMeter for bypassing Kerberos login challenges.